# Converting into roles

Tags: python, api, ansible, roles

This is part of the playbook i have written. But want to implement roles instead of using Api's. here you can see that there are more than 2 apis's and i have few more also in script. can you give any ideas to convert this into roles.How to modify this as roles

```
- name: Get df 
  uri:
    url: "{{ci}}"
    method: GET
    user: '{{ lookup("env", "@@@@@@") }}'
    password: '{{ lookup("env", "@@@@@@") }}'
    HEADER:
    Content-Type: application/json
    #body: "{{req_body|to_json}}"
    force_basic_auth: true
    status_code: 200,400,401
    timeout: 15
    validate_certs: false
    body_format: json
  delegate_to: ########
  register: df_response
- set_fact:
    df_response: "{{df_response}}"
    df: "{{df_response.json.result[0].comments}}"
  when: df_response.status == 200

- name: Get GroupName based on CI Name
  uri:
    url: "{{getgroup}}={{ BotCI_name}}"
    method: GET
    user: "{{!!!!!!!}}"
    password: "{{######}}"
    headers:
      #Authorization: "{{token}}"
      Content-Type: application/json
    #body: "{{BotCI_name/json}}"
    force_basic_auth: true
    status_code: 200,400,401,404
    timeout: 60
    validate_certs: false
    body_format: json
  register: inventorygroup

- name: Get HostName based Group Name
  # Get this from Ansible Tower
  uri:
    url: "{{^^^^^}}{{inventorygroup_hostresponse}}"
    method: GET
    user: "{{$$$$$$$$$$}}"
    password: "{{%%%%%%%%%%%}}"
    headers:
      #Authorization: "{{token}}"
      Content-Type: application/json
    #body: "{{/json}}"
    force_basic_auth: true
    status_code: 200, 400, 401,404
    timeout: 15
    validate_certs: false
    body_format: json
  register: hostname
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(Not tested) Create a file `<main folder>/roles/gen_token/tasks/main.yml` with the below contents

```
---
- name: Generate Token to run API calls to Ansible
  uri:
    url: {{url}}
    method: POST
    user: '******'
    password: 'aa********'
    HEADER:
    Content-Type: application/json
    #body: "{{req_body|to_json}}"
    force_basic_auth: true
    status_code: 200,400,401
    timeout: 15
    validate_certs: false
    body_format: json
  delegate_to: per0dans01
  register: yutoken
- set_fact:
    t_token_response: "{{yutoken.token}}"
  when: yutoken.status == 200

- debug:
    msg: "Token printed: {{yutoken}}"
```

Then call the role from main playbook `<main folder>/main.yml`

```
---
- hosts: all
  roles:
  - { role: gen_token, url: "http://1.1.0.1/api/v2/user/******/personal_token*/" }
  - { role: gen_token, url: "http:another/url/personal_token*/"
```

or

```
---

- hosts: all
  tasks:
  - include_role:
       name: gen_token
    vars:
      url: 'url1'
  - include_role:
       name: gen_token
    vars:
      url: 'url2'
```

Comment: i am currently using three files like these for a single playbook. each file has different url otherthan that all the codes are same. how to change those files with single one ?

Comment: updated the answer, please check if this is what you need

Comment: I have edited the question again...please check on that

Comment: is there any problem if you pass the variables to the role whenever there is a difference in the api call

Comment: No,it is my Fault that i did not notice it before. we are using different method,username and password. And also i have to register the output and call it while posting to servicenext.

Comment: you can pass all the vars in the role. - { role: gen_token, url: "http:another/url/personal_token*/, method: GET, username: user" . But I am not sure of the register variable

Comment: Then can i just create a new file for each api under tasks in roles

Comment: yeah i guess you can do that